How to get data from Mini App opened via direct link?
Is it possible to get data from Mini App opened via direct link (Example: https://t.me/botusername/appname). And are there other ways to open Mini App from a group chat if this is not possible? I can't find info about this problem in telegram bot API docs.
I tried to use InlineKeyboardButtons and KeyboardButtons but they don't work in group chats.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You can pass data by using query param startapp
https://t.me/botusername/appname?startapp=
